# Telling my neighbors to not blow his weedy lawn clippings onto my newly mowed lawn

Tags: conflict-aversion, etiquette, neighbors

I have new neighbors who are apparently not well versed in mowing their lawn, or neighborly manners.

When they first moved in, they did not have a working mower, only a very old push mower. After seeing their lawn uncut for a month I decided to be a 'good neighbor' and offered to mow their lawn for free, with my 26hp 54" lawn tractor.

I demonstrated to them how to mow a lawn correctly. They eventually went out and bought a riding mower which apparently only one of them can ride.

It's obvious this dude isn't happy about mowing the lawn. But when he mows every two weeks, he blows his grass into our subdivision streets and onto my front lawn that I have spent years trying to get weed and junk grass free. His side of the house between mine is nothing but weeds and junk grass full of seeds.

The first time he did it I calmly raked my yard and put it in a bag and placed it at the top of the drive.  The second time he did it, attempting to be non-confrontational but perhaps demonstrating that it was not okay to do it, I got on my lawn tractor and calmly blew his cut grass back onto his property. I did it while he was still outside and could see that I did it.

I'm waiting for the third time which will probably be today and if he should happen to do it again I am contemplating exactly what I plan to say to him and goes something like this:

> Hey how ya doin?  I noticed you have been relegated to mowing the lawn lately and I also noticed the past two times you've mowed you have blown your lawn clippings onto my lawn. I just want to let you know that is not okay.  The correct way to mow your lawn is to blow it to the inside of your property and not onto your neighbor's lawn.  I would appreciate it if this didn't happen again and if you need any additional lawncare advice, just ask.

I am open to advice, suggestions, or any other comments, just be nice :-)

Comment: Hey there Perplexed! I'm not sure what you want advice on exactly? Are you afraid that what you are planning to say is too confrontational?

Comment: Like Ælis said, we need to know more about what you'd like answers to focus on: Is it about how to tell? Is there something about your neighbours you haven't told us that makes you think your suggested line of approach won't work? Can you please clarify? Until then, I'm going to put this on hold, so no-one can answer it. This avoids it getting any answers that don't address the problem. Please [edit] your question to ask an actual question (take note of our [help/on-topic] too, some questions are off-topic here, please avoid those). If you need help, you can ping using @Tink in a comment.

Comment: FYI it sounds like you don't know how to mow your lawn.  You should never mow your grass in the same direction twice so it's unreasonable to ask him to always blow the clippings in the same direction.  You either want him to bag his clippings or get a better mulching blade.  His clippings going into your lawn isn't going to give you anymore weeds than his lawn already does.  Your imaginary property line doesn't change the fact that your adjacent lawns are actually the same.